# Er: Warning database has been locked for 0:00:10.000000. Make sure you always use the transaction object for database operations during a transaction

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to build a wallpaper app using Flutter and Firebase Firestore. When I try to load all the images(1000+) from firestore using streambuilder, I get the above warning and then my app crashes(lost connection to device). But when I try to load small amount of data(say about: 10-20 images) everything works fine.(I am using cached_network_image)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.